# Stop ENTER from submitting the containing form in Autocomplete plugin by Jorn Zaefferer

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I use Jorn Zaefferer's Autocomplete jQuery plugin which works great except for one thing - if a user is using his keyboard to scroll through the autocomplete options list and then presses Enter on the one he wants, it submits the containing form.

Im sure a cleverly placed `return false;` would sort this out - does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

My solution was to put an event handler on the text boxes that were autocomplete to prevent the Enter keypress being passed downward, like this:

```
    $('input[type=text].autocomplete').keydown(function(event){
        if ((event.charCode ? event.charCode : event.keyCode) == 13)
            event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    // Validate form fields here
});
```

The above would at least ensure that no matter how the form submit is triggered, you can capture and suppress it if necessary.